# mobile issues. pinch & zoom only certain region of the page (sencha vs jqtouch vs jquery mobile)

Tags: static, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch, jqtouch, fixed

I am making a small SVG widget aimed at iphones with a fixed footer.

The problem is I want to use native pinch & zoom that only affects everything bar this fixed footer.

However I cant use native pinch & zoom if i use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Which is needed I believe to standardize the 320px width across mobile devices?

My thought was then (dare i say it) an iframe for the pinch/zoom stuff above the fixed footer but you need 2 fingers to scroll an iframe and 99% of users wont know that (unless there is a simple js fix for that?)

Any help/guidance much appreciated.

Adi.

Comment: Any progress so far with that problem? I have similar requirements and my first approach would have involved an iframe as well. I'd be highly interested if you came up with a good solution.